# Evaluate a finite sum with four factorials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

> Given positive integers $k, m, n$ such that $1 \leq  k \leq  m \leq  n$. Evaluate
>
> $$ \sum^{n}_{i\mathop{=}0}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\cdot\frac{(m+n+i)!}{i!(n-i)!(m+i)!}$$

Any hints? I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: Maybe it have some connection to sums of binominals or multinomials? I mean $$ \sum^{n}_{i\mathop{=}0}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\cdot\frac{(m+n+i)!}{i!(n-i)!(m+i)!} = \sum^{n}_{i\mathop{=}0}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\cdot \binom{m+n+i}{i, n-i, m+i} = \\  = \sum^{n}_{i\mathop{=}0}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\cdot \binom{i}{i} \binom{n}{n-i} \binom{m+n+i}{m+i} = \sum^{n}_{i\mathop{=}0}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\cdot \binom{n}{i} \binom{m+n+i}{m+i} $$

Comment: The term is hypergeometric, so the techniques in [A=B](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) will tell you if there is a closed form. Computer algebra systems like [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks for this cool book recommendation!

Comment: Do you require an exact value, or is an asymptotic expansion enough? Any special values (ranges) of the parameters of special interest?

Comment: Exact value is required. This is an olympiad problem.

Comment: Probably not very helpful, but we can rewrite $i$-th element as a recursion:
$$a_i=a_{i-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+k+i}\right)\frac{(m+n+i)(n-i+1)}{l(m+l)}$$
where $a_0=\frac{1}{n+k}$ and then the sum is
$$\frac{(m+n)!}{n!m!}\sum_{i=0}^na_i.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer to collect some ideas.

Since
$\binom{m+n+i}{m+i}$
is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+i+1}}$ around $x=0$, we have:
$$ S = [x^n]\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k+i}\binom{n}{i}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{i}}\right),\tag{1}$$
where $\frac{1}{n+k+i}=\int_{0}^{1}y^{n+k+i-1}dy$ leads to:
$$ S = [x^n]\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{1}y^{n+k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\frac{y^{i}}{(1-x)^{i}}dy\right),$$
$$ S = [x^n]\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{1}y^{n+k-1}\left(1+\frac{y}{1-x}\right)^n dy\right),$$
$$ S = [x^n]\left(\frac{(1-x)^{n+k}}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1-x}}y^{n+k-1}(1+y)^n dy\right).\tag{2}$$
By setting $y=\frac{z}{1-z}$
$$ S = [x^n]\left(\frac{(1-x)^{n+k}}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\frac{z^{2n+k-1}}{(1-z)^{n+k+1}}dz\right)\tag{3}$$
we can see that the integral is just a value of the incomplete beta function, but I bet that other manipulations are more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is $$\frac{(m+n)!}{(n+k)n!m!}{}_3F_2(-n,n+k,m+n+1; m+1,n+1+k; -1)$$. Unfortunately there are not many closed form expressions known for these hypergeometric series at -1. A few like         http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(96)00154-9 may be able to map the format to $_3F_2(;;+1)$$ and be handled by Milgram's table in http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3126 .

Answer (score 0):

[maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s Zeilberger tells me:

```
GosperSum(factorial(m + n + i)/(factorial(i) * factorial(n - i) * factorial(m + i) * (n + k + i)), i, 0, n);
NON_GOSPER_SUMABLE
```

so there isn't a nice closed form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find this
 $$\sum^{n}_{i=0} \frac{(-1)^i}{n+k+i} \cdot \frac{(m+n+i)!}{i!(n-i)!(m+i)!}$$
can see  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=239364&sid=2fbf367cb9fab8240df03e632a41085a#p239364

Comment: Yes thanks, there was a typographical error in the question unfortunately.